# View 'Other Users' schemas as you can in SQL Developer

Tags: datagrip

I have an Oracle DB that where I use multiple schemas from the 'Other Users' objects in SQL Developer, and the login has permissions to all of them. Trying out DataGrip and I can't see the 'Other Users' in the tree and there is no obvious way to view those schemas. I confirmed I can query those tables in DataGrip (SELECT * FROM otheruser.table works just fine).

Is there a way to get those schemas's to show up in the database panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage seen schemas and databases in DataGrip go to the data source properties (**context menu | properties**) and select `Schemas` tab. There you can choose which schemas to show.

[image]